# How to import a react component with arrow function to app.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey Developers I am new to react js. I have made a react component named `todos.js` with arrow fuction in
`./Components/todos.js`

```
import React from 'react'

export const todos = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            todos works!!!
        </div>
    )
}
```

this is how my `app.js` look like

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './Components/header';
import Footer from './Components/footer';
import { Todos } from './Components/todos';
function App() { 
  return (
    <>
    <Header></Header>
    <Todos></Todos>
    <Footer></Footer>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`import { Todos } from './Components/todos';`  I am importing the `todos.js` file this way. But when I import that component to my `app.js` it throws error saying

```
Attempted import error: 'Todos' is not exported from './Components/todos'.
```

Comment: todos =/= Todos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be an `export const Todos`. The component name should be Capitalised it's a batter approach as react components.

**Todos.js**

```
import React from 'react'

export const Todos = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            Todos works!!!
        </div>
    )
}
```

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './Components/Header';
import Footer from './Components/Footer';
import { Todos } from './Components/Todos';

function App() { 
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Todos />
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all component name should be Capitalised.
Second use export default const Todos

Comment: The error got solved when i Capitalised the component function name. ```todo``` should be ```Todo```.